# Extending ProgressBar causes delay on first value change

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I've made a class which extends `ProgressBar` - mainly to allow more customization, so I can draw ticks on the bar, choose the colors I want, and get rid of the animation that you get by default, etc.  It works fine for the most part, but the first time the value changes, there's always a delay of about a second before it actually updates.  All subsequent changes happen immediately, it's only that first time going from 0 to 1 that it's delayed.  I'm trying to determine if there's some sort of built-in delay that I have to circumvent somehow?  Here's the relevant bits of my code:

```
public class FancyProgressBar : ProgressBar
{
    //... various properties and fields

    public FancyProgressBar()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public FancyProgressBar(IContainer container)
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;

        container.Add(this);

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rec = e.ClipRectangle;

        rec.Width = (int)(rec.Width * ((double)Value / Maximum)) - 4;

        if (ProgressBarRenderer.IsSupported)
            ProgressBarRenderer.DrawHorizontalBar(e.Graphics, e.ClipRectangle);
        else
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Gray, 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);

        rec.Height = rec.Height - 4;

        DrawBar(e.Graphics, new Color[] { Color1, Color2, Color3 }, e.ClipRectangle, rec);

        if (Ticks > 0)
        {
            int lineHeight = this.Height * TickHeight / 100;
            float spacing = this.Width / Ticks;
            for (int i = 1; i < Ticks; i++)
            {
                Pen pen = new Pen(new SolidBrush(TickColor));
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, new Point((int)(spacing * i)-2, Height), new Point((int)(spacing * i)-2, Height - lineHeight));
            }
        }
    }

    //This is broken out into a separate function because I have another version
    //that draws more than one bar.  Shouldn't make a difference though.
    private void DrawBar(Graphics g, Color[] colors, Rectangle clipRec, Rectangle drawRec)
    {
        using (System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush l =
            new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(clipRec, Color.Green, Color.Red, 0f))
        {
            System.Drawing.Drawing2D.ColorBlend lb = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.ColorBlend();
            lb.Colors = colors;
            lb.Positions = new float[] { 0, PositionColor2, 1.0f };
            l.InterpolationColors = lb;

            g.FillRectangle(l, 2, 2, drawRec.Width, drawRec.Height);
        }

        using (System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush l2 =
            new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(clipRec,
                Color.FromArgb(147, 255, 255, 255),
                Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255),
                System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientMode.Vertical))
        {
            System.Drawing.Drawing2D.ColorBlend lb = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.ColorBlend();
            lb.Colors = new Color[] { Color.FromArgb(40, 255, 255, 255), Color.FromArgb(147, 255, 255, 255),
                Color.FromArgb(40, 255, 255, 255), Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255) };
            lb.Positions = new float[] { 0, 0.12f, 0.39f, 1.0f };
            l2.InterpolationColors = lb;

            l2.WrapMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.WrapMode.Tile;
            g.FillRectangle(l2, 2, 2, drawRec.Width, drawRec.Height);
        }
    }
```

Edit:
I should state that I'm not using the ProgressBar as an actual progress bar.  It's not running while stuff is loading, just there to show some values in a UI, so there's not some other expensive computation going on at the same time necessarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally came up with a real solution here.  The ProgressBar stuff was completely unnecessary.  I just changed my `FancyProgressBar` to extend `Control` instead of `ProgressBar`, and then added fields for `Value`, `Minimum`, `Maximum`, and `Step`, which were really the only parts of `ProgressBar` I was still using, since I overrode the drawing part already.  Only other thing I had to add was to call `Invalidate()` on the progress bars whenever the value changed.  This did not work when extending from `ProgressBar`, which seems to have some sort of built in delay probably due to it being designed as a multi-threaded object.  Since I wasn't actually using it as a loading bar, the multi-threading was completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try your ProgressBar with BackgroundWorker because UI elements have a difference Thread. Like this:

```
    BackgroundWorker bwEx = new BackgroundWorker();
    bwEx.DoWork += bwEx_DoWork;
    bwEx.RunWorkerCompleted += bwEx_RunWorkerCompleted;
    bwEx.ProgressChanged += bwEx_ProgressChanged;
    bwEx.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bwEx.RunWorkerAsync();

    private void bwEx_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       yourProgress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void bwEx_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void bwEx_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Afraid I'm still missing something.  I can't figure out how this is supposed to change anything.  In place of `myProgressBar.Value = x;` I've put `bwEx.ReportProgress(X);`  It now works, but still has that 1-second delay the first time you do it, so nothing is fixed this way.  Also, this is really inconvenient, because I've got about a dozen FancyProgressBars on the screen, and setting up a BackgroundWorker for each of them seems like way too much code for no real benefit.  (It doesn't seem like there's an easy way to use one BackgroundWorker for multiple ProgressBars.)